# ¿Cómo recoger una ID en mongodb?

Tags: php, mongodb, vue.js

Estoy aprendiendo a trabajar con vue.js y mongodb y para practicar he realizado una pequeña aplicación de registro de usuarios/miembros con un CRUD.

El problema es que al realizar el EDIT y el DELETE necesito recoger el ID del usuario para hacer lo oportuno.

```
if($crud == 'delete'){
  $id = $_POST['$oid'];

  $bulk = new MongoDB\Driver\BulkWrite;

  $bulk->delete(['_id' => new MongoDB\BSON\ObjectID($id)]);

  $conn->executeBulkWrite('test.miembros', $bulk);

  $out['message'] = "Miembro eliminado correctamente";  
}
```

Necesito saber que necesito pasarle al POST

```
$id = $_POST['$oid'];
```

He probado el _id el $oid y no hay manera...
Espero que podais ayudarme. ¡gracias!

Asi es como hago la llamada al delete con la ayuda de axios.

```
    deleteMember(){
        var memForm = app.toFormData(app.clickMember);
        axios.post('api.php?crud=delete', memForm)
        .then(function(response){
                //console.log(response);
                app.clickMember = {};

                if (response.data.error) {
                    app.errorMessage = response.data.message;
                } else {
                    app.successMessage = response.data.message
                    app.getAllMembers();
                }
            });
    },
```

Comment: ¿Podrías editar tu pregunta y agregar el código que realiza la llamada `delete`?

Comment: acabo de añadir el codigo a la pregunta. un saludo

Comment: ¿Podrías agregar que obtienes si haces `console.log(JSON.stringify(memForm))`?

Comment: Sencillamente obtengo esto {}.

Comment: Eso quiere decir que debes tener un error ya que no se esta pasando los datos del `member`. Por las dudas ¿en que punto del `script` hiciste el `console.log`? Deberías de ponerlo junto antes de hacer `axios.post(...`

Comment: Justo ahi lo puse. El problema es que no se como obtener el ID de usuario en mongoDB. Si hago un var_dump de lo que recojo obtengo string(15) "[object Object]". No se como recoger el valor hexadecilmal de 24 caracteres que genera mongoDB.